# How to set background color of android app and background of action bar

Tags: android, xml, colors, background, android-actionbar

I am trying to modify my app to have a dark blue action bar with a light blue background.  So far I have only been able to make the entire app dark blue.  How can I modify my code to keep the action bar the color it is now but make the background with the team numbers a light blue?  Please note my apps minimum API is 14.

[image: RR Pit Scout Blue]

I am currently using the following code in my styles.xml:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/teamLightBlue</item>
</style>

<!-- Activity themes -->

<style name="Theme.Base" parent="android:Theme.Light" />

<style name="Theme.Sample" parent="Theme.Base" />


<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
    parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/teamDarkBlue</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the parent of CustomActionBarTheme to your actual custom theme (e.g. parent="AppTheme") instead of the default android Holo.Light.DarkActionBar. Or you could just add <item name="android:background">@color/teamDarkBlue</item> to your CustomActionBarTheme style. Either should work

Comment: Also worth noting: you're setting both your application's background and your ActionBar's background to be the same color by the looks of it, so you're going to have to change one of them if you want to see a difference

Comment: @Guardanis I changed parent to app theme.

<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
        parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
    </style>

and changed my color to light blue in apptheme

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/teamLightBlue</item>
    </style>

yet the entire app including the action bar turns light blue.

Comment: I updated the code in my original question so it's easier to read.

Comment: Are you using the new Toolbar or the "old" Action Bar? If you are using ActionBar why don't you use the new Toolbar, it's easier and you can change everything you want.

Comment: @porthfind I am using the old action bar because my minimum API is 14.  Toolbar requires API 21 and most of the devices I have run Kit Kat.  Toolbar does look a lot easier to use though but Lollipop isn't out on enough devices yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to use **Theme.AppCompat**, you can change Action Bar's background color using:

```
<item name="colorPrimary">#ffffff</item>
```

but if you choose the Holo one, you can change that color using

```
<item name="android:colorPrimary">#ffffff</item>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know your code is good instead of `Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar` as its not part of AppCompat v7. Use this instead

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle" tools:ignore="NewApi">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/teamDarkBlue</item>
    <item name="background">@color/teamDarkBlue</item>
</style>
```

It should work fine!